# How could I run a remote command within a Gitlab CI Pipeline using sshpass and print the output/depend on the result of that command?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sshpass

I want to run a script that is on a separate server within a Gitlab CI job and have the job print the output of that script and depend on the script's result.

I'm using sshpass to get around inputting a password like this:

```
- sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@SERVER 'command_to_run'
```

and I've tried redirecting output just to at least try and see that the command is actually running:

```
- sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@SERVER 'command_to_run' > command_log.txt
- cat command_log.txt
```

but regardless, all I get in the pipeline logs after it runs that line is:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'SERVER' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

and it isn't even waiting for `command_to_run` to complete before moving on.

Is there any way to get the command output logs and depend on the remote command_to_run within a pipeline job?

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: What command are you running on the remote system? Is it a script? What commands does the script run?

Comment: In my case, I needed "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" flag :) It's helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the command output logs

The output of the command should be shown in the Gitlab logs. Check the script if it using some form of redirection e.g. `>`

> depend on the remote command_to_run within a pipeline job?

Assuming nothing goes wrong with ssh itself, its exit code is the exit code of the last command executed on the remote host. (If something does go wrong, its exit code is 255.)

So you could check `$?` which contains the exit code of the last command. And depend on it in order to impose a specific logic. E.g.

```
  - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@SERVER 'command_to_run'
  - |
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
       ...All well case...
```

Be aware that the `exit code of a script` would be the `exit code of the last executed command` in that scipt.

If your case is to `fail` the job, if even a single error was encoutered in the remote command.

Add `set -e` to the start of script, which would make the script fail at the first command error

Answer (score 0):

You can use below pipeline to archive it in a batter way.
But Before going for the pipeline just define the variable in the **Settings--> CI/CD-->Variables**
and add variable username, password, serverip

```
AWS:
  stage: aws
  before_script:
  - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$AWS_PASSWORD" | ssh-add -
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan $AWS_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ssh -t -t $USER@$IP "command to run in remote"
```